# Can i import sql dump in postgresql database

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have mysql dump localhost.sql. But when i try to import this to postgresql db i got errors like this:

```
psql:localhost.sql:10: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "sql_mode"
psql:localhost.sql:11: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "autocommit"
START TRANSACTION
psql:localhost.sql:13: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "time_zone"
psql:localhost.sql:24: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `peoplfv0_WPGHJ` DEFAULT CHARA...
                           ^
psql:localhost.sql:25: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USE"
LINE 1: USE `peoplfv0_WPGHJ`;
        ^
psql:localhost.sql:39: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `dl_affiliates` (
                     ^
psql:localhost.sql:47: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `dl_affiliates` (`affiliates_id`, `affiliates_na...
                    ^
psql:localhost.sql:65: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `dl_artist` (
                     ^
psql:localhost.sql:94: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
```

Can i convert this sql dump to postgresql format to import data from mysql dump?

Comment: MySQL and Postgres use different syntax here and there. So you cannot directly use a dump from MySQL that is written in MySQL specific syntax, you need to transform it in Postgres syntax first.

Comment: i understand this, but how i can transform in Postgress syntax directly this dump

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `--compatible` option for mysqldump:

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql dbname > dbname.sql
```

According to MySQL documentation:

> **--compatible=name**
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
>   with older MySQL servers. The value of name can be ansi, mysql323,
>   mysql40, postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options,
>   no_table_options, or no_field_options. To use several values, separate
>   them by commas. These values have the same meaning as the
>   corresponding options for setting the server SQL mode. See Section
>   5.1.10, “Server SQL Modes”.
>
> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It
>   only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for
>   making dump output more compatible. For example, --compatible=oracle
>   does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.

As the documentation says it does not guarantee full compatibility with Postgres syntax, but it helps a lot and sometimes could be the solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the dump output still has MySQL version comments like `/*!40101 ... */` and those are hard-coded in mysqldump printf statements. There's no option to convert these to uncommented syntax. So one would have to edit the dump output anyway.

Comment: That compatible option is worthless. It might change a few small details, but in the end it's still MySQL syntax.

Comment: These comments (i.e. comments like /*!40101 ... */) are conditional-execution tokens, not real comments (it may look that way, but is not). So removing such comments could lead to incomplete restore on Postgres. In the documentation is reported: it does not guarantee compatibility, it only helps for a much closer compatibility.